# How to place text on top of the image inside container with relative width 80%

Tags: css

i want to place text on top of the image inside container with width 80%
conainer.width 80% - code below not working
conainer.width 100% - code below working
[screen shot of my brouser](http://s3.postimage.org/5tjnodflv/result.png)

```
<style type="text/css">
.conainer {
    margin: auto;
    width: 80%; /* change that to 100% code will work */
    border: thin solid #000;
}
h2 { 
   position: absolute; 
   top: 200px; 
   left: 0; 
   width: 100%; 
}
.image { 
   position: relative; 
   width: 100%; /* for IE 6 */
}

</style>

<div class="conainer">
    <div class="image">
        <img src="img/banners.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" />
        <h2>some text gos here</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It works http://jsfiddle.net/MU9QT/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok! i found the problem change top 200 => top 0

```
h2 { 
   position: absolute; 
   top: 0px; 
   left: 0; 
   width: 100%;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just set the **background** of your div, instead of trying to place the **h2** on top of an **img** tag

Answer (score 0):

It works for me. Is there any more code?

Answer (score 0):

I think the most code-efficient and compatible method would be to define your banner image as the background-image of div.image using CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `h2` style as

```
h2 { 
   position: fixed;//yours is on top of image but absolutely positioned, so not visible
   top: 200px; 
   left: 0;  //Specify where you want to put your image with top and left properly now.
   width: 100%; 
}
```